# What are the different ways of highlighting (or emphasising) words in English typography?

Tags: history, typography

I know the following techniques are used for words in print :

Italics, Underline, Bold, ALL-CAPS, Change-Of-Font, Enclosing-In-Single-Quotes, Enclosing-In-Double-Quotes, Change-Of-Colour, & Letter-Spacing.

Additionally, for sentences, we have Indentation.

Other languages may have other techniques (eg Over-Lining for Arabic & Emphasis-Dots for Chinese & Japanese), but are there any other (historical or current) techniques for English ?

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29

Here I'm not much interested in web or electronic media, where Blinking-Text & Moving-Text might be used.

Comment: It's unclear what your purpose is.  The ways of highlighting are determined by the technology, which can be a typewriter, ASCII text file, Word, Adobe, TeX, etc, or some printing industry typesetting tool.

Comment: @HotLicks , I am more interested in "print" techniques , which will include printing industry typesetting & human handwriting too, but will exclude web or ebook or electronic media.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the technology.  Most "modern" typesetting tools can do a large variety of techniques, but some are far more difficult to use for particular cases, making the techniques impractical for frequent use.

Comment: This belongs on [writer.se].

Comment: Suggesting migration to [writers.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because typography is not in the scope of ELU.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your "words" to mean not just individual words but phrases, sentences, paragraphs, and arbitrary sections of text:

Change-of-font: font face and/or font-size and or font-weight.

Also, large word-initial capital can be used for emphasis with the first word in a section of text or paragraph.

Block caps.

Sidebars and insets (with a different background color, e.g. pale yellow or light gray) and/or with a contrasting border-color, are another way of isolating and emphasizing a chunk of text.

Word-balloons have an arrow or pointer-shape or a tapered tail that connects the words inside the balloon with a specific place in the main body of the text.

Magnified insets (sometimes shaped like a magnifying glass or loupe) can also be used to draw attention to a word or section of text.

Ordered lists and bulleted lists.

Columns.

Icons or symbols or dingbats in the margins can be used to identify the focus of a section of text (e.g. caveats and warnings, special importance, etc).

Comment: Not exactly emphasis, but there's superscript/subscript.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good ideas from Tim Romano, I would add these:

- Rotation of text (especially handy for labeling charts/graphs, and for fitting text in tight columns, especially column headings).
- Borders around individual letters, words, phrases or paragraphs.
- Combinations of bold+underline, bold+italic, italic+underline, and bold+italic+underline. (implicit in the stating of the question, but listed here for completeness)
- Strikethrough or double-strikethrough  (often used to indicate deleted text)
- Superscript & subscript (handy for footnote references as well as math & chemistry
- Drop Caps (might be what Tim Romano meant by "large-word initial capital....")
- SMALL CAPS (might be what Tim Romano meant by "block caps")
- Shadow and 3D text effects
- Highlighting  (a subset of colored backgrounds)
- Offsetting text vertically up or down.  (like super/subscript, but using full-sized text)
- Variations in line spacing
- Switching from left-justified to right-justified, full-justified or centered.
- Block text (set off by different margins than the rest of the text)
- using ordinary keyboard characters ( / $ & @ ! [ ] { } # % ^ * + = _ \ |~ > < ) to set off or point out other text (or just to make decorative borders)
  ->@@@@###____###@@@@<-

As far as I can tell, the techniques available from pre-Gutenberg ahes to present day have not changed much; only the tools have changed (libraries of digital fonts rather than hand-drawn calligraphy; million-color digital palettes vs hand-mixed paints or inks; etc.).